# Simplify $(xy^{-1})/(y^2/x^3)^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need to simplify this equation:

$$(xy^{-1})/(y^2/x^3)^{-1}$$

So far I have

$= \frac{x/y}{1/(y^2/x^3)}$

But don't know what to do next. Any help much appreciated

Comment: Please make sure I edited your question correctly

Comment: Can you explain how you got there? Just so that we know what techniques you are (and aren't) familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$(xy^{-1})/(y^2/x^3)^{-1}=(xy^{-1})\times\left(\frac{y^2}{x^3}\right)^{+1}=\frac{x}{y}\times\frac{y^2}{x^3}=\frac{y}{x^2}$$ **provided** $$x\ne0, y\ne0$$

Comment: ;-) $+^++^++^++$

Comment: @amWhy: It is very kind of you considering my small attempts here. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use $x^a x^b = x^{a+b}$ and $1/x^a = x^{-a}$ to simplify equation to form something like $x^a y^b$.